# No Internet in snappy 15.04 stable

Tags: networking, 15.04, virtualbox, ubuntu-core

It seems that none of my two snappy systems can access the Internet. When I run 'snappy list -u' I get the following error message:

```
Get https://system-image.ubuntu.com//ubuntu-core/15.04/stable/generic_amd64/index.json: dial tcp http://91.189.88.35/:443: i/o timeout
```

The above I get from a virtual snappy installation on VirtualBox. I also get a similar error from a snappy 15.04 stable (running from SD card) on a BeagleBone Black. The board is connected to LAN (because I can ssh to it from my desktop) but apparently it does not have Internet (pinging www.google.com, it says 0 packets received).

The BeagleBone Black is a new installation, but I am sure that I had Internet on the virtual machine before.

Does anybody else have this problem, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. The network at my place required MAC address registration, and I forgot to do that for my BeagleBone Black. After registering my BBB's MAC address in the online registration form, I can make it see the Internet.

Here I just document the process in the hope that another networking-noob like me could benefit. Please correct me if I am doing something totally wrong or inefficient.

There are two LAN sockets in my room, one connected to my desktop and one for my BBB. I checked my own internal IP address using:

```
ifconfig | grep "inet addr:"
```

And that was something like '21.263.89.63'. 
Then, I searched for my BBB in the network, assuming that it also has an IP like '21.263.89.xx':

```
sudo nmap -PR -sP 21.263.89.63/24
```

This will give me a long list of all devices of mine and my colleagues. I looked for this:

```
Nmap scan report for 21.263.89.54
Host is up (-0.099s latency).
MAC Address: aa:bb:CC:dD:Ee:ff (Texas Instruments)
```

From this I know the IP address of my BBB. Now I can ssh into it:

```
ssh ubuntu@21.263.89.54
```